# Trouble with a:visited pseudoclass... Links all showing as the same color after they are "visited" despite having different colors in css

Tags: css, hyperlink, pseudo-class

I am having trouble with the a:visited (or one of the other a maybe?) pseudoclass. I want to have the links show up as different colors in different elements (black in .link-box and red in #main-menu regardless of if they have been visited or not), which they do AT FIRST, but once they are "visited" links, they are all the same color (red).

Any idea what I've done wrong here?

```css
.link-box {

  background-color: blue;

  
}

.link-box a:link,

a:visited,

a:active {

  color: black;

  padding-left: 10px;

  font-weight: bold;

}

.link-box a:hover {

  color: #D31900;

  text-decoration: none;

}


#main-menu {

  height: 60px;

  background-color: black;

}

#main-menu a:link,

a:visited,

a:active {

  color: red;

  text-transform: uppercase;

}

#main-menu a:hover {

  color: #FF6600;

}
```

```html
<div class="link-box">

 <a href="">Link box link</a>

</div>


<div id="main-menu">


    <a href="">main menu link</a>
  

 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `a:` pseudo-classes in the cascade matters.

The conventional mnemonic to remember in which order to style the `a:` pseudo-classes is:

**LoVe HAte**

*ie. Link, Visited, Hover, Active*

Re-order your stylesheet, like this:

```
.link-box a:link,
.link-box a:visited {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.link-box a:hover {
  color: #D31900;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link-box a:active {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


#main-menu a:link,
#main-menu a:visited {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#main-menu a:hover {
  color: #FF6600;
}

#main-menu a:active {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for the mnemonic, didn't know that.